# GraphQL requests using two groups of AND expressions grouped by Or operator

Tags: content-delivery, graphql

In the example below:
https://docs.rws.com/816112/933327/sdl-tridion-sites-9-5-main-documentation/graphql-requests-using-boolean-expressions-with-more-than-two-operands
A combination of two-operand Boolean expression with a third operand are used to form a three-operand Boolean expression. Something like:
A or (B and C)
Where A, B and C are Boolean expressions

Is it possible to use groupBy to have two three-operand Boolean expressions grouped by or operator. Something like:
(A and B and C) or (D and E and F)
Where A, B, C, D, E and F are Boolean expressions

I'm trying to implement such query to get results based on two item types: Page and Component. Page, where I can search in page and its components indexed content. And Component where I can search in binary components (PDF documents).
So I have the following query:

```
{
  searchByCriteria(
        sortBy: {fields:["modifiedDate"], sortAsText: false, sortingDirection: DESCENDING},
        criteria: {
        field: "itemType",
            value: "page",
            and: {
              groupBy: {
                field: "dynamic+appearinsearch",
                value: "yes",
                and: {
                  groupBy: {
                    field: "content+english",   
                    value: "Governance",
                    or: {
                      groupBy: {
                        field: "itemType",                      
                          value: "component",
                          and: {
                            groupBy: {
                              field: "binaryContentType",       
                                value: "application"
                              and: {
                                field: "content+general",       
                                    value: "Governance"
                              }
                            } 
                          }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
    }) {
....
....
....
  }
}
```

For above query I'm only getting results for the first three-operand boolean expression, like the other one after or operator is totally ignored.